# Verify code execution

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I use this code to delete user from database:

```
task :delete_username, [:user_name] => :environment do |environment, args|

    value = args[:user_name].to_s

    puts "Deleting #{value}"

      MerchantUser.where(:login => value).delete

  end
```

How I can verify that user is successfully deleted? For example that is the proper way to sue try-catch in this code?

Comment: You could make a select for this user after deleting it and when the database returns an error you can try/catch it like you said.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to this part of the code.

Comment: You need to make a select to get a result from database mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using [`destroyed?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroyed%3F) :

```
task :delete_username, [:user_name] => :environment do |environment, args|
  value = args[:user_name].to_s
  user = MerchantUser.where(:login => value).first

  if user
    puts "Deleting user \"#{value}\""
    user.destroy
    if user.destroyed?
      puts "  User \"#{value}\" successfully deleted!"
    else
      raise "Problem while deleting user \"#{value}\""
    end
  else
    puts "No user with login \"#{value}\" found"
  end
end
```

You could also call [`destroy!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/destroy!) and let Rails raise an exception if the record cannot be deleted.

Note that `MerchantUser.where(:login => value)` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which doesn't respond to `delete` or `destroy`.

You should use `MerchantUser.where(:login => value).first` or `MerchantUser.find_by_login(value)`